# How can I ever root my Samsung Galaxy V, SM-G313HZ, Android version 4.4.2? Please help

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, odin, stock-rom

I've tried everything on the internet to root my phone and followed the exact procedures – but when I try to install CWM or `.tar` files through Odin mode, I seem to always lose my recovery mode:

Pressing <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> button then <kbd>power</kbd> button won't work to boot to recovery mode. It just displays a very small red exclamation point at the topmost left of the screen and the logo at the center of the screen then it will turn black, then back again at the logo with the (!).

I still can open my phone but can't boot to its recovery mode and still not rooted. Good thing, there is a way to recover my recovery mode by reflashing my Android's stock ROM through Odin mode, which works 100% in reflashing back my recovery mode. I do, still, have to factory reset my phone after reflashing through the newly flash stock ROM.

Now the question is, how can I ever root my phone?

Comment: how about trying with king-o-root....though the device is not listed....but you can give it a try http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/download.htm

Comment: Tried that already. I've also tried Kingroot and Vroot (now Iroot) both are of Chinese origin but they still can't root my android. They're harmless somehow to use on my android. These one click rooting apps don't actually root your device, they're just taking over the official root of your android if your android is already rooted then verify it.

Comment: I am talking about the PC version of king-o-root. It worked perfectly fine for my samsung galaxy-S-duos GT-S7562. I also verified the root two ways..

Comment: I think that will take too long to download on my computer. I've also tried Iroot PC version but failed again to root my phone. Should I try other PC versions of some one click rooting apps? These PC versions of rooting android also come with other apps that automatically install while rooting.

Comment: We'll its just around 30 mb....since that method worked I haven't tried other methods to root.... maybe others here can help.....

Comment: I will try all possible ways of rooting just for my phone. I'm persistent! Persistent just to overcome  the conditions & limitations KitKat 4.4.2 has. (i.e. Can't write, save or paste files on external sd card.)

Comment: I may have a way but I need to ask you those questions , 1/ do you have access to download mod (volume down + home +power) ? 2/ my methode will make you use warranty if you are out of EU is it worth it for you ?(personally I never cared about warrenty). 3/what OS do you use on PC ?

Comment: 1.) Yes, I have access to Odin download mode. _______________2.)And yes, I would likely use a warranty.________________3.)The OS of our computer is Microsoft Windows 2007 / 7.

Comment: click the volume- or volume+ when seeing the logo of android with exclamation point.

Comment: i also use samsung galaxy v duos i rooted already go to this site www.kingroot.net